# Data Loader - Opportunity Stage Value Does Not Select

Tags: opportunity, data-loader

I am working with data loader looking to automate a pipeline upload process and creating a template.
Currently I have been able to match all of my fields
[image]

When double checking the upload, the Opportunity Stage does not automatically select, and is greyed out. It needs to be manually selected to register what stage it is at.

[image]

I have searched the Opportunity Objects to double check the mapping and cannot see anything wrong.
Has anyone come across this before? Do the Opportunity Stages need to be manually selected?

Thanks in advance,